# Кириллица в Unicode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал функцию, которая шифрует текст по методу Цезаря. Работает она по методу превращения каждого символа в числовое значение Юникода:

```
function caesarShift(text, shift) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            var c = text.charCodeAt(i);
            console.log(c.toString(16));
            if(c >= parseInt('65', 16) && c <= parseInt('90', 16)) 
                result += String.fromCharCode((c - 65 + shift) % 26 + 65); //верхний регистр(латиница)
            else if(c >= parseInt('97', 16) && c <= parseInt('122', 16))
                result += String.fromCharCode((c - 97 + shift) % 26 + 97); //нижний регистр(латиница)
            else if(c >= parseInt('410', 16) && c <= parseInt('42F', 16))
                result += String.fromCharCode((c - 410 + shift) % 32 + 410); //верхний регистр(кириллица)
            else if(c >= parseInt('430', 16) && c <= parseInt('44F', 16))
                result += String.fromCharCode((c - 430 + shift) % 32 + 430); //нижний регистр регистр(кириллица)
            else
                result += text.charAt(i); //без изменений(пробелы, знаки восклицания)
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Но вот беда - Юникод работает только с латиницей. Можно ли как-то транслировать кириллицу в Юникод и передавать её в качестве параметров в функции? Нашёл вот [этот метод](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685859/javascript-processing-cyrillic-input), но не уверен, что это именно то, что мне нужно.

Comment: `console.log(c)` при передаче кириллицы в качестве аргумента функции возвращает `1090 1077 1089 1090` для слова `тест`. Хотя в [таблице символов Юникода](https://unicode-table.com/ru/#myanmar) символы с таким индексом обозначают Бирманский язык. wtf?

Comment: Вы не то смотрите. `1090` — это в системе счисления 10, а в системе счисления 16 это будет `442` — а это как раз буква «т» https://unicode-table.com/ru/0442/

Comment: Поменяйте log на `console.log(c.toString(16))` и всё поймёте

Comment: @andreymal да, понял. А как мне сравнивать значения в шестнадцатеричной форме исчисления? Я не могу сделать сравнение `c <= 44f`.

Comment: А зачем? Переводите всё в десятичную и там сравнивайте) Хотя в js есть форма записи для них `0x442`

Comment: @andreymal теперь после шифрования вместо кириллицы выводятся символы `ǅƸǄǅ`. Что с этим делать?

Comment: А это уже вам решать как цезаря реализовывать) Можно и так оставить)

Comment: @andreymal так проблема в том, что обратно оно дешифруется в таком же формате :D

Comment: Ну не знаю, я дописал обработку русских символов аналогично обработке английских из вашего примера, и у меня отлично всё работает для любых положительных shift

Comment: @andreymal изменил код в вопросе. Просмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А зачем тег `jquery`?

Comment: Надо не `parseInt('430', 16)`, а `0x430`, и не просто `430`, а `0x430`, я ж писал выше

Comment: @Other там остальной кусок кода на jQuery. Я его хотел вставить, по этому и написал jQuery по инерции.

Comment: @andreymal точно, не заметил.

Comment: @andreymal перепишите комментарий в качестве ответа на вопрос. Почему проблему, как решённую :)